# ReCaptcha in JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, recaptcha

I was wondering why the ReCaptcha in not showing in  my application.
I have followed series of tutorial in the web.
But still only the SUBMIT button is shown.

Please see my code below.

```
   <%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha" %>
 <%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaFactory" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <html>
      <body>
        <c:out value="${errorMessage}" />
        <form action="" method="post">
        <%
ReCaptcha c = ReCaptchaFactory.newReCaptcha("my public key", "my private key", false);
          out.print(c.createRecaptchaHtml(null, null));
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Of course, I edited the keys in my code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: add recaptcha4j-0.0.7 jar in your project and try

Answer (score 1):

Use this.This has a tutorial to help you out http://springinpractice.com/2008/03/13/how-to-recaptcha-your-java-application/
This will also help you out http://rominirani.com/2010/02/22/episode-15-using-a-captcha-in-your-google-app-engine-application/